# PHP - check if the current ID is the same as previous in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I have this `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($dataSet1 as $data) {
    $result .= '<tr>';
    $result .= '<td bgcolor="#EBEBEB" width="100" class="veranda"><a href="/lookup.php?userID='.$data['CUST_ID'].'">' . $data['CUST_ID'] . '</a></td>';
    $result .= '<td bgcolor="#EBEBEB" width="100" class="veranda">' . $data['LAST_NAME'] . '</td>';
    $result .= '<td bgcolor="#EBEBEB" width="100" class="veranda">' . $data['PHONE'] . '</td>';
    $result .= '<td bgcolor="#EBEBEB" width="100" class="veranda">' . $data['ORD_COUNT'] . '</td>';
    $result .= '<td bgcolor="#EBEBEB" width="100" class="veranda">' . date('m/d/Y' ,strtotime($data['DATE_LAST'])) . '</td>';
    $result .= '</tr>';
}
```

**EDIT**

I need to separate  the users with bottom border, based on  $data['CUST_ID'];

Example:

```
$data['CUST_ID'] = 2;
$data['CUST_ID'] = 2;
$data['CUST_ID'] = 2;
bottom-border;
$data['CUST_ID'] = 25;
$data['CUST_ID'] = 25;
bottom-border;
$data['CUST_ID'] = 2131;
bottom-border;...
```

Comment: Store previous value in a variable.

Comment: `foreach(...) { if ($prev != $data) { do new stuff; $prev = $data; } }` basically

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just save the previous ID in a variable and check it, and update it, in each loop iteration:

```
$previousId = '';
foreach($dataSet1 as $data):
    if ($previousId !== '' && $previousId !== $data['CUST_ID']) {
        // put a border
    }
    $previousId = $data['CUST_ID'];
    $result .= '<tr>';
    $result .= '<td bgcolor="#EBEBEB" width="100" class="veranda"><a href="/lookup.php?userID='.$data['CUST_ID'].'">' . $data['CUST_ID'] . '</a></td>';
    $result .= '<td bgcolor="#EBEBEB" width="100" class="veranda">' . $data['LAST_NAME'] . '</td>';
    $result .= '<td bgcolor="#EBEBEB" width="100" class="veranda">' . $data['PHONE'] . '</td>';
    $result .= '<td bgcolor="#EBEBEB" width="100" class="veranda">' . $data['ORD_COUNT'] . '</td>';
    $result .= '<td bgcolor="#EBEBEB" width="100" class="veranda">' . date('m/d/Y' ,strtotime($data['DATE_LAST'])) . '</td>';
    $result .= '</tr>';
endforeach;
```

Comment: This is not working as I intend. Need a minute to rephrase the question.

Comment: I just edited the question. Can you take a look once again please?

Comment: It really was only a tweak to change

Comment: Yea, I realised that :). I am in my 30th hour of coding, so my brain is fried :/. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a variable outside the loop that will keep this information:

```
$previous = null;
```

So inside your loop you can ask:

```
if ($data['CUST_ID'] == $previous) {
    // current customer id same as previous id
} else {
    // not the same
}
```

And in the very end of your loop set the precious variable to the current one:

```
$previous = $data['CUST_ID'];
```

Comment: I just edited the question. Can you take a look once again please?

Answer (score 1):

```
/* You have to declare a variable outside of the foreach loop
which will hold your value for previous id as you proceed through the loop.*/

$prev_cust_id = '';    

foreach($dataSet1 as $data):

  // Then inside the loop, declare a the border styling as empty.
  //Make it not empty and as you need it to be if your IDs do not match.

  $add_border = '';
  if($data['CUST_ID'] != $prev_cust_id && $prev_cust_id != ''){    
      $add_border = 'style="border-bottom:1px solid black;"';
  }

  $result .= '<tr>';

  // Assign border styling variable to your HTML element.

  $result .= '<td '.$add_border.' bgcolor="#EBEBEB" width="100" class="veranda"><a href="/lookup.php?userID='.$data['CUST_ID'].'">' . $data['CUST_ID'] . '</a></td>';
  $result .= '<td bgcolor="#EBEBEB" width="100" class="veranda">' . $data['LAST_NAME'] . '</td>';
  $result .= '<td bgcolor="#EBEBEB" width="100" class="veranda">' . $data['PHONE'] . '</td>';
  $result .= '<td bgcolor="#EBEBEB" width="100" class="veranda">' . $data['ORD_COUNT'] . '</td>';
  $result .= '<td bgcolor="#EBEBEB" width="100" class="veranda">' . date('m/d/Y' ,strtotime($data['DATE_LAST'])) . '</td>';
  $result .= '</tr>';

  // Set current ID as previous ID before ending the loop for current ID.
  $prev_cust_id = $data['CUST_ID'];

endforeach;
```

Comment: I just edited the question. Can you take a look once again please?

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly with comments, please let me know if you need explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Edited it once again to make it more compact, using some sharp thinking in John Conde's answer.